# DatabaseError: no such column error

Tags: django, django-models

So I have a model that I wanted to add ImageField to, so I typed in
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images')

I then ran syncdb and went into the shell:

```
python2 manage.py syncdb
python2 manage.py shell
```

I then imported the model and tried

```
"model".objects.get(pk=1)
```

I get the error:

```
DatabaseError: no such column: people_people.picture
```

When I run manage.py sql for the model

```
"picture" varchar(100) NOT NULL
```

is in the database.

What solutions do you guys have? I can't delete the data in the database.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As noted in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) `syncdb` doesn't add columns to existing tables, it only creates new tables.

I suggest running

```
python manage.py sqlall <your_app>
```

Looking at the sql it outputs for the table you're changing, and then running

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

in order to manually issue an `ALTER TABLE` command.

In future, you might like to use a migration tool like [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities that to get this error 1) You added extra field to model after doing the syncdb. 2) you added new class to model.py file in django.

Solution for this is:

First install south by using command

```
for windows: **easy_install south**     //for that you need to go to the script folder of python folder in c drive.

for linux: **sudo easy_install south**
```

Then follow the steps which are included here migration tutorials

step1- python manage.py schemamigration your_app_name --initial

step-2 python manage.py migrate your_app_name
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As of 1.7 [migrations within Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/) replaces South.

Create a new set of migration instructions by running the following command in terminal:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

Check the output in the migration folder it creates to make sure they make sense then run the following terminal command to complete the migrations:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

That's it.

Running migrations this way allows others to implement the same migrations instead of having to manually implement db changes on every machine using the code. On the new machine all they have to run is:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I might be nice to expand this answer, showing how you would use migrations to achieve the stated goal.