# Django - Create Category Views doesn't create Column

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am doing this tutorial [tangowithdjango 5 Models and databases](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/models.html)

In the exercises it asks to create a views and likes column with default=0 in the categories. Then to use population script to update them with values.
Direct quote from site

> Update the Category model to include the additional attributes, views
>   and likes where the default value is zero.

So I have gone and created the categories in models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import default

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Then I sync.db
However the columns aren't creating I get this error from the view.

```
Exception Type: DatabaseError at /admin/rango/category/
Exception Value: no such column: rango_category.views
```

What is wrong with how I have created them? Do I have to remove all my database tables and recreate them?

**Edit**: The solution to [Incorrect Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323659/databaseerror-no-such-column-error) doesn't resolve the issue, as well as my answer I thought would. Deleting the database and re-syncing didn't resolve the issue with creating the population script.

The sql appears to be ok I am unsure what is wrong.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "rango_category" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "views" integer NOT NULL,
    "likes" integer NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "rango_page" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "category_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "rango_category" ("id"),
    "title" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    "url" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "views" integer NOT NULL
)
;

COMMIT;
Finished "/home/sayth/workspace/tango_project/manage.py sql rango" execution.
```

Even re deleting database and redesigning and recreating models doesn't reolved.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "rango_category" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
;
CREATE TABLE "rango_page" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "category_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "rango_category" ("id"),
    "title" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    "url" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "views" integer NOT NULL,
    "likes" integer NOT NULL
)
;

COMMIT;
Finished "/home/sayth/workspace/tango_project/manage.py sql rango" execution.
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323659/databaseerror-no-such-column-error

Comment: @laike9m       I wish that possible answer you posted would resolve it just like the answer I posted but alas it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried `south`?

Comment: @laike9m       I just want to start at the start and get these basics right.

Answer (score 1):

Ah yes I overlooked a warning in the doc.

> Warning Whenever you add to existing database models, you will have to
>   delete the database file and then re-sync the database by running
>   python manage.py syncb again. This is a drawback of Django 1.5.4, and
>   can be quite frustrating. If you however add a new model, you can
>   syncdb your database without having to delete and recreate it. You
>   must therefore bear this in mind when tweaking your database: new
>   models will be synchronised with syncdb - but changes to existing
>   models will not be. When adding a new model to your application’s
>   models.py file, you can simply run the following command to
>   synchronise the database with the command $ python manage.py syncdb.
>   When updating an existing model to your application’s models.py file,
>   you must perform the following steps. Delete the database. Recreate
>   the database with the command $ python manage.py syncdb. Populate the
>   new database with data. Deleting and recreating the database from
>   scratch is a frustrating process. A possible solution to this issue
>   could be to use a third party application like South to handle
>   database schema migrations (changes to your models). South is
>   currently in active development and is considered a standard solution
>   for Django schema migrations until this functionality becomes part of
>   the standard Django codebase. We don’t cover South here - but the
>   official South documentation provides a handy tutorial if you’re
>   interested. If you don’t want to use South, we discuss a technique in
>   Section 5.8 to speed up the updating process. You may have also
>   noticed that our Category model is currently lacking some fields that
>   we defined in Rango’s requirements. We will add these in later to
>   remind you of the updating process.

And it appears migrations in core will not be available until django 1.7.

I had incorrectly updated the populate script it should have looked like.

```
def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0):
    p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title, url=url, views=views)[0]
    return p

def add_cat(name, views=0, likes=0):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name, views=views, likes=likes)[0]
    return c
```

see

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19759473/461887

[django migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/)

Comment: Use south for now, everyone does. (or in this particular case you can drop the database file and remake it, as I doubt you have data you need to save). I've heard good things about tangowithdjango, but it seems very strange to me that they don't explain South in any detail as it's pretty much essential. (until 1.7)